# How to compare string values in one column, one by one, grouped

Tags: python

I have data frame like this 
and I want to track changes but within every RB group, so I want to add column if there is change set 1, else 0

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```py
import pandas as pd
from calendar import month_abbr

months = [month.lower() for month in month_abbr[1:]]
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'RB': [2335] * 4 +  [3567] * 4 + [1245] * 4,
    'time': months[:4] * 3,
    'value': ['good day'] * 2 + ['may be'] * 2 + ['what'] * 4 + ['sure'] * 3 + ['no']
})

df['time'] = pd.Categorical(df['time'], categories=months, ordered=True)
df = df.sort_values(['RB', 'time'])
df['previous'] = df['value'].shift()
counts = df.groupby(['RB'], sort=False).count()['value']
counts.iloc[0] = 0
counts = counts.cumsum()
cols = df.columns.to_list()
df.iloc[counts, cols.index('previous')] = df.iloc[counts, cols.index('value')]
df['change'] = (df['previous'] != df['value']).astype(int)
cols = ['previous', 'value']
change_counts = df[df['change'] == 1][cols].groupby(cols).size().reset_index()
change_counts.columns = ['from', 'to', 'counts']
change_counts = change_counts.sort_values(by=['counts'], ascending=False)
df = df.drop('previous', axis=1)
print(df)
print()
print(change_counts)
```

Output:

```
      RB time     value  change
8   1245  jan      sure       0
9   1245  feb      sure       0
10  1245  mar      sure       0
11  1245  apr        no       1
0   2335  jan  good day       0
1   2335  feb  good day       0
2   2335  mar    may be       1
3   2335  apr    may be       0
4   3567  jan      what       0
5   3567  feb      what       0
6   3567  mar      what       0
7   3567  apr      what       0

       from      to  counts
0  good day  may be       1
1      sure      no       1
```

Comment: Even though I don't understand much of the code it works perfectly, thank you very much

Comment: It is more clear to me now, thank you :) I have one more question, if I would want to see how many RB changed from sure to no, from sure to good day, from sure to maybe, from what to sure etc, so all combination are valid and also "sure" to "no" is different from "no to "sure", do you have idea how to detect how many RB are in each combination ? Since there are a lot of combination I would like to see if some are appearing more often ? Thank you so for all the help you already gave me .

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thank you but this is taking to long, more then hour just for the first definition

Comment: Could you give a count on the number of rows per RB? What do you mean by `taking more than 1 hour for just the 1st definition`?

Comment: I have around 400 000 RB multiplied by 4 months, which is around 1,6 million records.     def get_changes - takes around 45 minutes to finish

Comment: @MinaLukic Please confirm if the updated code works for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new column as **change** for the difference, but firstly group by them [RB with value].

```
df.sort_values(['RB'], inplace=True)
df['change'] = (df.value != df.value.shift()).astype(int)
print(df)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't have column "change", that is the exact column I want to make.

Comment: @MinaLukic I changed the answer.

Comment: This is wrong. You're comparing across categories. The comparison should be done only within the group. For instance, the 1st row should have 0.

Comment: This way change is 1 every time a new RB comes up, and that should be 0